# gdb: How can I execute gdb commands only if an environment variable is set?

Tags: gdb

How can I execute gdb commands only if an environment variable is not set?

Something like:

```
 if ENV[$VERBOSE]
   printf "a=%d\n", $a
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Something like:

```
set var $v = getenv("VERBOSE")
if $v != 0
   printf "a=%d\n", $a
end
```

Comment: I get: `getenv("AAA"): Undefined command: "getenv".  Try "help".` on GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.1-2ubuntu2) 10.1.90.20210411-git.

Comment: @SRobertJames Updated.

Comment: Still error: `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`